# to shown output 10 fold confusion matrix

Tags: python, cross-validation, decision-tree, tfidfvectorizer, decisiontreeclassifier

helo. i have this kind of problem where i couldn't get the output for each fold's confusion matrix, how do i do with the code?

[image]

[image]

I expect to get all fold confusion matrix result, I've tried the code that i put, but the result is different when i try to calculate it manually and only get one confusion matrix